# How to Querying to make compressed parquet file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill, dataformat

I made data format changing program using apache drill.

In this program, If csv file convert to json, json file made in hdfs

But I want to output file is compressed.

Is it possible?? If it possible how to make it??

Comment: If output data size is smaller than before in not increasing performance time, every way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set compression type in apache drill.

From Documentation,

> You can set Drill query planning and execution options per cluster, at the system or session level. Options set at the session level only apply to queries that you run during the current Drill connection. Options set at the system level affect the entire system and persist between restarts. Session level settings override system level settings."

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET `option_name` = value;
```

option name **store.parquet.compression** You can select Compression type from the allowed values: **snappy, gzip, none**

More info [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuration-options-introduction/).